# Как удалить кавычки из строки php?

Tags: php

Приходят данные из базы:

```
$str = 'с.т. "АСТРА"' //тип string UTF-8
```

Не могу удалить двойные кавычки.
Пробовал:

```
str_replace('"', "", $str );
preg_replace("/\/\/.*?\n/", "\n", $str);
stripslashes();
```

Ничего не работает.

Желаемый результат

```
$str = 'с.т. АСТРА'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не сохранили результат работы str_replace() в переменную:

```
$str = 'с.т. "АСТРА"';
$str = str_replace('"', '', $str);

echo $str;
```

---

Смотреть **[демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57082345bafc1e7791a1e01c4dfc69de83975689)**

Comment: Да нет, так тоже не работает. Тут проблема в входных данных $str получает данные из базы  тип string UTF-8. Распечатываю на экран данные из базы, копирую строку в $str =  str_replace('"', "", 'с.т. "АСТРА"') возвращает - с.т. АСТРА. Ставлю переменную из базы $str =  str_replace('"', "", $str) возвращает - с.т. "АСТРА".

Comment: @Vital посмотрите пример по ссылке _(клик по кнопке "Execute Code")_

Comment: Экранирование кавычек и удаление функцией stripslashes(), не помогает

Comment: @Vital А строку `с.т. "АСТРА"` вы видите в вебе, в консоли или в отладчике? Если в вебе, то, возможно, у вас вместо `"` в строке стоит `&quot;`

Comment: строку с.т. "АСТРА" вывожу в вебе вижу " когда на переменную накладываю htmlspecialchars() вижу &quot;

Comment: @Vital `mb_str_replace` попробуйт

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае с 99% долей вероятности у вас в строке вместо символа двойной кавычки находится  `&quot ;` . Пробуйте так.

Answer (score -1):

Мне ничего не помогало по замене двойных кавычек пока не пределал следующий костыль:

```
$str = str_replace(chr(38), "", $str);
$str = str_replace("quot;", "", $str);
```

Код для функции chr() нашел из функции ord($str[номер символа где кавычка]).